# using numbers in a string

Tags: c#

Can I use numbers while using `String` data type?

Comment: Of course. What isn't working for you?

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can, and if you want to use them as numbers you can parse the string. E.g. for an integer:

```
string numberAsString = "42";
int numberFromString;
if (int.TryParse(numberAsString, out numberFromString))
{
    // number successfully parsed from string
}
```

[TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) will return a bool telling if the parsing were successful. You can also parse directly if you know the string contains a number - using [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx). This will throw if the string can't be parsed.

```
int number = int.Parse("42");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have numbers in a `string`.

```
string s = "123";
```

..but `+` will concatenate strings:

```
string s = "123";
string other = "4";
Debug.Assert(s + other != "127");
Debug.Assert(s + other == "1234");
```

Answer (score 2):

Numbers can be easily represented in a `string`:

```
string str = "10";
string str = "01";

string str = 9.ToString();
```

However, these *are* strings and cannot be used as numbers directly, you can't use arithmetic operations on them and expect it to work:

```
"10" + "10"; // Becomes "1010"
"10" / "10"; // Will not compile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily store numbers *as a string*:

```
string foo = "123";
```

but that only helps you if you actually *want* numbers in a string. For arithmetic purposes, use a number. If you need to display that later, us a format string.

Answer (score 1):

```
String number1 = "123456";
```

keep in mind. using that number for arithmatic purpose, you have to convert that string into proper type like

```
int number1Converted = Int32.Parse(number1);    
int.TryParse(number1 , out number1Converted );
```

for double

```
double doubleResult = 0.0;
double.TryParse("123.00", out doubleResult);
```

Comment: surely String number1 = "1"; :P